# Can the raspberry Pi 2 B be used as a media centre with Windows 10 IoT?

Tags: windows, windows-iot

I have my Raspberry Pi B+ hooked up to an HDD and serving my media successfully.
I never hooked it up to a TV as a media centre since I wasn't to convinced on the device's strength to do this reliably.

Not knowing much about the W10 IoT, I would like to know if the PI2 is up for the task to stream the data from my B+ model and play back 1080p content without stuttering (provided the network can handle the bandwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went out and bought a Pi2, hooked it up to my TV's USB port for power.
Installation and configuration of OSMC was easy and straightforward. No need for any Linux knowledge (not that would have been a problem).

It works out of the box and very fluently, I have the menu at 1080p and 60hz, controlled with an Android device as remote. No stutters or lag or any of that.

Haven't found the need to buy the extra licenses since it seems to work without them.

No need for IoT W10 after all.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Raspberry pi model B with Raspbmc during 2 years playing 1080 and 3D movies (20GB file) from a DLNA server conected to the same switch without any issue. Now the distro is called [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/).

You can also implement projects like [Hyperion](https://github.com/tvdzwan/hyperion/wiki) - [Raspbmc+Hyperion](http://www.it-cave.com/raspbmc-hyperion/) ;-)

Comment: My experience is that DLNA doesn't stream subtitles etc (not tested with a PI, just with 'smart' TV's and PS3)
My hope was that the Windows install would be as straight forward as a ms desktop where I just install VLC/MPC/... and a bunch of codecs to not worry about this. (I've also got samba running on the B+)

Comment: Xbmc/Kodi can connect to samba too. I've already watched content with subtitles, but them was on the same file... Give it a try.

With an app like [Yatse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree) you can even choose between audio/subs from a smartphone.

Comment: Smartphones do the job just fine with samba, but I need my TV to do this properly, thats why I was contemplating on buying a B2 for the ease of use that windows OS brings with it. However the W10 IoT isn't a full w10OS, so hence my question.

Comment: I was saying that you can control the raspberry running xmbc/kodi from your smartphone. As you say, W10 IoT is not intended for running as a desktop distro.

If you are worried just about subs [Kodi - Subtitles](http://kodi.wiki/view/Subtitles)

Comment: ok, Kodi it is then, I guess... can it handle software codecs on the pi2 or should I still buy the hardware license?

Comment: I've never buyed it.